# Is trimming the method input String parameter a bad practice?

Tags: java

I'm debating myself whether it is a bad practice to trim the input String arguments of a method? I personally don't like modifying the input arguments but wondering if trimming is Ok?

I've code something like below

```
private Order retrieveOrderDetails(String productId, String cardNumber, Date purchaseDate) {
    validateInputs(trim(productId), trim(cardNumber), purchaseDate);

    List<Order> orders = pullOrdersByCardNumber(trim(cardNumber));

    return retrieveOrderDetails(orders, trim(productId), purchaseDate);     
}
```

Instead of using trim() in multiple places, is it acceptable to do something like below?

```
private Order retrieveOrderDetails(String productId, String cardNumber, Date purchaseDate) {
    productId = trim(productId);
    cardNumber = trim(cardNumber);

    validateInputs(productId, cardNumber, purchaseDate);

    List<Order> orders = pullOrdersByCardNumber(cardNumber);

    return retrieveOrderDetails(orders, productId, purchaseDate);       
}
```

Comment: If the String is input and can have extra spaces, then what choice do you have?

Comment: Why did you write your own `trim` function?

Comment: Within the method, if your string inputs are expected to be trimmed every time it is used, I see nothing wrong with trimming it at the top as you did in your example.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch its not a custom defined method but its a static import from the StringUtils class from apache commons.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The strings should **already be trimmed** by the time they reach `retrieveOrderDetails()`.

Needing to trim strings implies that they're coming from user input: form fields, a configuration file, etc. Trimming whitespace from user input is a job for user interface code or file reading code. You should not be mixing layers of abstraction, handling both UI and business logic in the same function.

Don't trim the strings here, and don't check that they're trimmed. Don't worry about trimming at all. It's the caller's problem, not this function's.

If you want to be really pure you could even replace the strings with domain-specific classes. You already have `Date purchaseDate` rather than `String purchaseDate`. Do the same thing for the other two parameters. Then where trimming belongs becomes clear: not here.

```
Order retrieveOrderDetails(ProductId productId, CardNumber cardNumber, Date purchaseDate) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Orthogonal to John's point (which is "you shouldn't need to do this here"), you seem to be asking if it is acceptable to modify a method parameter variable.

It really comes down to readability.  Which of these three versions do >>you<< think is more readable?

```
public void test(String arg) {
    // repeat the trim computation
    use(trim(arg));
    use2(trim(arg));
}

public void test(String arg) {
    // modify the argument
    arg = trim(arg);
    use(arg);
    use2(arg);
}

public void test(String arg) {
    // use a local variable
    String trimmedArg = trim(arg);
    use(trimmedArg);
    use2(trimmedArg);
}
```

Your answer will probably depend on the context.

But really, it is up to you to make your own judgement.  We can't tell you which version you will find more readable.  It is readability for you and your colleagues that matters.  After all, you will be the ones who (may) need to read this code in N years time.

There will be small performance differences, but that should not be your primary criteria or deciding, unless you have strong evidence that this code is performance critical.

Comment: I just posted this question to see if there is any strong argument to say there is any concerning violation or if it is considered as a bad coding practice doing it this way. Your response certainly helps. Thank you very much for your response!

Comment: "Bad practice" is subjective.  Seriously.  Especially in points of programming style.  Whether something is a "violation" or not is up to you and your organization's policy on adherence to a specific style guideline.

Comment: (My personal opinion is that all 3 forms would be acceptable ... )

Comment: I prefer the idea of massaging the input at one location only.  If this were a team effort (or perhaps even a solo project) I would probably use assertions to verify data formats at critical locations as an aid to debugging.

Comment: That is the point that John makes.  It was not my intention to repeat John's Answer :-)

Answer (score -3):

If your business function doesn't change if the input is trimmed or not so trimming is fine.

But if there is a different logic between trim and with-out trim, so you can't do that by default.